# MySQL client for iOS?

Tags: ios, database, mysql

I'd like to be able to manage my MySQL databases from my iPad. I currently use [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) on my Mac, and I love it.

The app must

- Support connecting to remote databases
- Support tunneling over SSH
- Make a command line (I.e. to issue `SELECT * FROM WHERE...` and `INSERT INTO...` type things) available
- Allow access to all databases that my current user has access to.
- Show a nice GUI for creating and modifying table schema

Nice to have:

- Free is always nice, but I'm absolutely willing to shell out some dollars.
- iPhone support, but that's rather far-fetched for something this advanced.

Is there an app that meets these criteria?

Comment: I wonder if you can use Prompt for this, since it's a terminal client. See related stackexchange question: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/41932/is-there-a-terminal-like-app-for-ios. I would try SSH, then mysql from the command line.

Comment: You could also use [Cathode](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cathode/id656982811?mt=8)... It is very much like Prompt, just with a different interface. You can see a comparison of Prompt and Cathode [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/the-two-best-ssh-clients-for-ios-go-head-to-head-prompt-vs-cathode/).

Comment: Check out "Navicat for MySQL", it's quite expensive (20€), I haven't tried it myself but from its description in the App store it seems to have every feature you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a list of SQL clients that I have tried in the past, all seem to have a limitation in one area, whilst being stronger in others. *MySQL Editor Pro* seems to be your best bet, IMHO. Hope this helps.

[MySQL ODBC](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-odbc/id409303944) (FREE, but basic and limited)

> **Description**
>
> With MySQL ODBC you can finally manage MySQL servers any where , any
>   time . This software was designed to provide all functionalities that
>   you can have in your computer .

[MySQL QueryDB Client](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-querydb-client/id576948046) (FREE)

> **Description**
>
> The easiest way to view data from your MySQL databases on your iPhone
>   or iPad! Optimized for flakey cellular connection, QueryDB provides
>   the best way to mine your databases away from your desktop. Easily
>   create queries using the schema viewer or export CSV data to external
>   apps.

[MySQL QueryDB SSH Client](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-querydb-ssh-client/id585493931) (SSH version of the previous client - not FREE)

> **Description**
>
> The easiest way to view data from your MySQL databases on your iPhone
>   or iPad over an SSL tunnel! Optimized for flakey cellular connection,
>   QueryDB provides the best way to mine your databases away from your
>   desktop. Easily create queries using the schema viewer or export CSV
>   data to external apps.

[MySQL Editor Pro](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mysql-editor-pro/id414309098) (Seems to fulfill your requirements, but the most expensive)

> **Description**
>
> MYSQL EDITOR IS A FULLY FEATURED MYSQL CLIENT
>
> ---
>
> Features:
>
> 1. MySQL over SSH connections
> 2. Manage MySQL DATABASES
> 3. View Server variables
> 4. Manage USERS and PRIVILEGES
> 5. Manage TABLES, VIEWS, TRIGGERS, KEYS
> 6. VIEW, ADD, UPDATE, DELETE, FILTER, ORDER rows of TABLES and VIEWS in
>      an awesome Table View
> 7. RUN, SAVE, OPEN, EXPORT & IMPORT (Via iTunes) SQL scripts
> 8. Script Editor with a great SYNTAX HIGHLIGHTING support
> 9. GENERATE DDL SCRIPT for the entire DATABASE and for TABLES, VIEWS,
>      TRIGGERS, and KEYS in a particular
> 10. Contains FULL MYSQL SYNTAX REFERENCE and allows to SEARCH in it
> 11. Supports iPhone, iPod and iPad
> 12. Supports iOS 4.3 to 5.0

Answer (score 0):

You might like my app [SQLPro for MySQL](https://itunes.apple.com/app/sqlpro-for-mysql/id1270754173)

- It allows you to connect to remote database servers.
- It allows for SSH Tunnelling (currently only password authentication is supported, but I will be adding public key authentication soon).
- It allows you to run inserts, selects, etc.

  - The query editor contains syntax highlighting and autocomplete.
  - Multiple queries can be run at once, allowing you to navigate between multiple results.
  - You can also save queries for future use.
- It displays database entries, allowing you to pick tables, views, stored procedures, etc and get quick direct access.
- It supports both iPhone and iPad (and has specific iPad Smart Keyboard support as well).
- Its completely free for a single database connection.

I believe the only thing not listed in your list is:

- Show a nice GUI for creating and modifying table schema.

I plan on this in the future (my macOS version of SQLPro for MySQL supports a GUI, but I haven't finished adapting to the iOS platform yet).

Some extra features that you may also like:

- Query results can be edited or even deleted (with confirmation) directly.
- Images stored in a database are detected and can be previewed or exported.
- Query results can be exported in multiple formats such as CSV, JSON or XML. Exported files can be opened directly into other application such as Numbers or Excel.

To make it very clear, I am the developer of this app. I love any feedback positive or negative about the app.

Comment: 6 euro per month. does nothing without it.

Answer (score 0):

Zing Data is an iOS (and Android) client for mySQL that is free for up to 10 people in an organization, offers built in graphing and data export, and has shared questions / @mentions to collaborate with colleagues.

https://www.getzingdata.com/

Web support coming soon as well.

Comment: Welcome Zack!  Do you have any affiliation with this product, or is it just something you recommend from personal experience?  Thanks!